# Add new columns in between other columns using script

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have SSIS package that reads XML file and put the data in database tables. In SSIS package I have added column names between two columns and I changed my table design exactly same way. That is , lets say, in SSIS package mapping I added new columns col2 and col3 between col1 and col4; then I modified my table accordingly (added new columns col2 and col3 between col1 and col4). This worked for me in Test server as I have proper access to it.

However, for UAT, to add new columns in between two columns I have to create a script and give to DBA.

I tried this:

```
update [information_schema].[columns]
set ordinal_position = 2
where table_name = 'Report_JR'
and column_name = 'col2'
```

I'm getting error: Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

How can I add new columns in between two existing columns? Is this error I'm getting due to permission issue? Please help.

Comment: Don't use ordinal position, use column names. SSIS does *not* require any specific ordering. Did you try mapping the columns at all? Why do you think you need to change the order of the columns?

Comment: No. I have not tried with column names. How can I do it? Frankly speaking , I want to maintain all the names and its orders in same manner through out all ( XML file -> SSIS mapping -> DB table column)

Comment: What *have* you done? You can't use an SSIS dataflow *without* using mapping. Didn't you click on the link between the source and the target? And why do you want to maintain order at all? Are you really going to delete the entire table and reload it? Column order means byte placement in the data files

Comment: SSIS package is already developed and working fine in PROD. As I get few new columns in XML file , I just did few modification to the package to accommodate these new XML fields; and i maintained same order in test DB table as XML field order. Worked find for me in Test server. So, do you think, if I'll add columns at end of all columns, in the table, it will map automatically?

Comment: What you are asking is "Can I hack an SSIS package and hide some new columns in there withouth updating the metadata"? I wouldn't want (allow) such a thing to run in production. As you already found out, it's very easy to break.